# Entity Framework ObjectContext life cycle using WCF Ria

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I'm currently reading through the self-paced training kit for the 70-516 exam (accessing data) and I'm in the chapter about Entity Framework.

I'm at a point where it talks about the ObjectContext and it inheriting IDisposable for cleanup. This brought up a few questions that I can't seem to get an exact answer on when researching. I'm just trying to understand how things work.

---

**SCENARIO:**
I've created a Silverlight Application using WCF Ria and Entity Framework and use MVVM Lite pattern. I made my EDMX and created a domain service called FamilyService, which I use as FamilyContext in the silverlight application. I create a method called GetFamilyMembers that returns data from the FamilyMember table.

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public partial class FamilyService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<FamilyEntities>
{
    public IQueryable<FamilyMember> GetFamilyMembers()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.FamilyMembers;
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel I create an instance of the FamilyContext when it constructs and null it on cleanup.

---

1) When I null the FamilyContext object, does it do anything with the ObjectContext on the server? I ask this because I never manually create or dispose of it in the domain service.

2) I understand that when I run a query in Entity Framework, it caches the data. In the RIA scenario, does the data cache on FamilyContext on the client application, or does it still reside on the ObjectContext on the server? I'm just curious if the ObjectContext holds the cache since each viewmodel in my application creates its own instance of the FamilyContext, wondering if the viewmodels are lightened by the cleanup but can still take advantage of the caching.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't create or dispose the `ObjectContext`? How can that be?

Comment: I dont manually do it, i'm assuming its in the LinqToEntitiesDomainService base class? Updating the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate a little more.

The [DomainService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.domainservice%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) (your FamilyService) is part of your server logic and an instance of the service will be created each time a request/method call (such as `Query`, `Update`, `Insert`, `Delete`, `Invoke`) is made on your service. This is done by the ASP.NET / WCF RIA Services runtime.

*If you want to control how instances of DomainServices are created you need to implement your own [DomainServiceFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.domainservice.factory%28v=vs.91%29.aspx). But this is an advanced scenario.*

So each request gets its own instance of your `DomainService` and so will the `DomainService` have its own instance of the `ObjectContext`. When the call is finished the ObjectContext gets disposed. Caching in this scenario only occurs when you query the ObjectContext multiple times during the request.

A [DomainContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.domaincontext%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) is a stateful client-side representation of a domain service, providing access to all the functionality of the service. It provides a cache (aka. EntityCollections) that contains the entites loaded from the `DomainService`. The cache is also used to update or delete loaded entites and to insert new entities. Changes on the cache need to be submitted, so that the corresponding methods are called on the `DomainService` to update, delete or to insert your entities.

Instances of your DomainContext are created using the constructors of the class and its normally up to you to create and cleaning up instances of the DomainContext. So setting the DomainContext to null does nothing on the server side.

Comment: Thanks, I believe you have cleared this up. Just to double-check, my FamilyContext of each viewmodel (created on constructor of vm and nulled on cleanup event of vm) has an independant cache of client-side data based on its own calls to the domain service. On each call, the domain service creates an instance of the objectcontext, uses it, then disposes of it, so all cached data on the ObjectContext is then gone. So all in all, I should be good on the cleanup since the domain service handles the server-side object, and I'm manually cleaning up my client-side FamilyContext. Sounds right?